# showing hiding div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all I have the following html code

```
<div id="orderlist">
    <div class="panel" id="1">
        <div class="p_header">Order No: 1
            <input class="ordview" type="button" value="View Details"/>
            <input class="select" type="button" value="Add"/>
        </div>
        <div class="p-content" style="display:none;">
            <table>
                <tr><td>Contact Person:</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Telephone:</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>E-Mail:</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Address:</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Code</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>City</td><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following jquery to toggle it but it is not working, cannot figure out why though

```
$("body").on('click',".ordview",function(){
   $(this).closest('div.p-content').css('display','block');
   alert('view button clicked');
});
```

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, you should better define what's not working. Also, rephrase the title to better reflect your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.closest()` goes up the DOM and `p.content` isn't an ancestor, but `div.panel` is. Use:

```
$("body").on('click', ".ordview", function () {
    $(this).closest('div.panel').find('div.p-content').toggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c0gjn9kt/2)**

Comment: perfect didn't realise closest on ly went up the dom, only had to change to toggle for my code to do what i wanted. And thanks baxri, what you said was exactly what i had planned once i figured out the right selectors ;)

Comment: This Code cannot toggle the div why this is marked as correct ?

Comment: @baxri - If the OP needs to toggle instead of only show, he merely needs to replace `.show()` with `.toggle()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code to show/hide details**

```
  $(".ordview").bind('click', function () {
      $(this).parent().next().toggle();
  });
```

Comment: And if there's more than one `.ordview` or `.p-content`?

Comment: if there is more then one p-content try this I edited my code with parant and next

Comment: please mark this if I Helped to toggle p-content div

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use the toggle() command. Below funciton works and can check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jawilliams346614/y7nyd3ae/1/)

```
$("body").on('click',".ordview",function(){
   $(this).closest('div.panel').children('div.p-content').toggle();
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jawilliams346614/y7nyd3ae/1/)